# The app crashes when opening image_cropper in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, crash

My app keeps crashing when I try to open image cropper in release mode.

I added everything in the `manifest` as directed in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper):

```
<activity
       android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

How I use it:

```
Future<void> _cropImage(File imageFile, int index) async {
if(imageFile != null){
  File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: imageFile.path,
      aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0),
      compressQuality: 100,
      maxHeight: height,
      maxWidth: width,
      androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
        toolbarTitle: "",
        toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
        statusBarColor: Colors.black,
        activeControlsWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      )
  );

  setState(() {
    compress(cropped, index);
  });
}}
```

As soon as I start the app in release mode, the following error message appears:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(13412): Process: com.packages.xxx, PID: 13412

E/AndroidRuntime(13412): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method 
asAttributeSet(Li/a/a/a;)Landroid/util/AttributeSet; in class Landroid/util/Xml; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.util.Xml' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at a.a.n.g.inflate(Unknown Source:21)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source:6)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:4212)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at androidx.fragment.app.d.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source:2)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at a.a.n.i.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source:2)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at androidx.appcompat.app.g$j.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source:8)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at a.a.n.i.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source:2)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at androidx.appcompat.app.j.m(Unknown Source:25)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at androidx.appcompat.app.j$a.run(Unknown Source:2)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7959)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)

E/AndroidRuntime(13412):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

How can I fix this?. Thanks.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will go through multiple solutions try them and tell me which one is your problem

1- in your `build.gradle(Module : app)`  you will find this section **remove it**

```
if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
&& !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
details.useVersion "27.1.1"
}
if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
&& !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
details.useVersion "1.0.1"
}
if (requested.group == "androidx") {
if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
details.useVersion "${targetSdk}.+"
}
```

2- Try adding the needed permissions to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

3- Try changing the gradle version into something like

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 do not work. To step 1: I can't find the code or it never existed before :(

Comment: have you check build.gradle in app folder ?

Comment: You can check it in the other comment

Comment: well .. try this package https://pub.dev/packages/image_crop

Comment: I already looked at the packedge yesterday, but it bothered me that you couldn't rotate the image. But it works in release mode and is therefore better than nothing. Thank you very much for the quick and good answers :)

Answer (score 0):

package/android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
        def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
        if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
                localProperties.load(reader)
            }
        }
    
    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    
    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
        // Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.packages.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    }
```

Comment: To follow up on this response - I had the same issue with image_cropper causing the android app to crash in release mode. I created a new flutter project and compared my android/app/build.gradle and android/build.gradle files with those in the new project. My build.gradle files were outdated and didn't mention kotlin at all. I copied some of the kotlin stuff over and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the below code change fixed it:

> **Add 'release' block inside the android in app/build.gradle file like give below**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

> **Create if not, 'app/proguard-rules.pro' file and add the following**
> **lines:**

```
-dontwarn com.yalantis.ucrop**
-keep class com.yalantis.ucrop** { *; }
-keep interface com.yalantis.ucrop** { *; }
-keep class androidx.appcompat.** { *; }
```

After adding the above code, the release mode worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because I only added the UCropActivity text into the AndroidManifest.xml within the Debug folder. It needed to be added to the AndroidManifest.xml within the Main folder as well for release to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have declared the UCropActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Open the file and add the following lines if they are not present:

**`Android->app->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml`**

`<activity android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>`